# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.emoji2.viewsintegration.EmojiTextViewHelper

Tags: android-studio

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.emoji2.viewsintegration.EmojiTextViewHelper
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:201)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:135)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:235)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEmojiTextHelper.(AppCompatEmojiTextHelper.java:43)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.getEmojiTextViewHelper(AppCompatTextView.java:137)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setFilters(AppCompatTextView.java:224)
at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1613)
at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:968)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:113)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:108)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:228)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:930)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:950)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:328)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:396)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:209)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:608)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:734)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

i tried changing apis but nah ...